# Why jar doesn't work with command line?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I'm making a project to modify a .wav file to .flac file, I use the class http://javaflacencoder.sourceforge.net/javadoc/index.html. My project in IDE eclipse works well. But when I exported it into .jar and run it with command line on linux. There is the error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javaFlacEncoder/FLAC_FileEncoder
    at speech.Speech.main(Speech.java:44)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javaFlacEncoder.FLAC_FileEncoder
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 1 more
```

Without idea, I can't understand why. Could anybody have the same problem? Could you show me how to resolve it? Thanks,

Comment: Whats the command you're typing on terminal? Does your project reference any external libs? Try adding -cp PATH of your libs.

Comment: Did you export the external lib when building the jar ?

Comment: Did you provide proper classpath for executing jar?

Comment: look at the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java

Comment: @AndreDuarte: I use this command line: java -jar project.jar Audio.wav. When I created the project, I have added some externel libraries. Could you show more clearly how to add -cp PATH in my libs? Sorry for this basic question, I'm beginning on linux :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably add a classpath entry to let Java know of your librarie.

Typically, you must do:

```
# generate the classpath entry
declare classpath=$(for jar in lib/*.jar; do echo ":$jar"; done)
# remove the first character (':').
classpath="${classpath:1}"
java -cp "${classpath}" -jar yourjar.jar
```

Or:

```
# the same code that generate classpath
export CLASSPATH="${classpath}"
java -jar yourjar.jar
```

Also, in the manifest of the jar, [you can list them the `Class-Path` entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse takes care of setting up the classpath for the execution of your Java program; you probably failed to replicate this on the command line. There are several options:

1. if starting with `java <main_class_name>`, then add the `-cp` argument listing all the dependency JARs;
2. if starting with `java -jar <jar_name>`, then make sure the JAR's manifest (MANIFEST.MF) includes the `Class-Path` entry, which lists the other JARs it depends on;
3. create an "uberjar" which contains all the necessary classes. Maven's *shade* plugin can do that for you.